# Possible to save an integer array using NSUserDefaults on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to save an integer array using NSUserDefaults on the iPhone?  I have an array declared in my .h file as: `int playfield[9][11]` that gets filled with integers from a file and determines the layout of a game playfield.  I want to be able to have several save slots where users can save their games.  If I do:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject: playfield forKey: @"slot1Save"];
```

I get a pointer error.  If it's possible to save an integer array, what's the best way to do so and then retrieve it later?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can save and retrieve the array with a NSData wrapper

ie  (w/o error handling)

Save

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&playfield length:sizeof(playfield)];
[prefs setObject:data forKey:@"slot1Save"];
```

Load

```
NSData *data = [prefs objectForKey:@"slot1Save"];
memcpy(&playfield, data.bytes, data.length);
```

Comment: It seems to work using memcpy(&playfield, data.bytes, data.length); instead of len.length.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Consider using functions like OSSwapHostToLittleInt and OSSwapLittleToHostInt in case one day the iPhone OS changes to big-endian for some reason.

Comment: @epatel I used your code converting Array to Data & storing in NSUserDefaults but I am not able to get convert the data to Arrray.Is it possible to get the same data back in the Array using your code?

Answer (score 8):

From [Apple's NSUserDefaults documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A default’s value must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

This is why you are getting the pointer error.

You have several options (in order of recommended usage):

1. Use an `NSArray` of `NSArray`s to store `playField` in your application

   Keep playField as an array of `int`, but fill an NSArray with numbers before saving to `NSUserDefaults`.

   Write your own subclass of `NSArchiver` to convert between an array of integers and `NSData`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to convert this to an object. You can use NSArray or NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Just use NSArray instead of normal C array then it will solve your problem easily.