# NSKeyedUnarchiver memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have problem with this code, it's working on debug environment. On the instruments I'm seeing memory leak problem on this function,  instruments is giving warning that

Category    Event Type  Timestamp   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
27  SocialNetwork   Malloc  00:19.951   0x3d64d20   80  Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]

```
- (NSMutableArray *)GetDataInstanceToUserDefaults{
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
NSData *storedObject = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"MyDataKey"];
NSMutableArray *data;   

if(storedObject != nil)
{       
    NSArray *savedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedObject];
    if(savedArray != nil)
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:savedArray];
    else
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}else{
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
}   
return data;
```

}

I didn't understand where is the my problem ?

Thank you for your support

Edit : By the way I should give more detail about this problem,this function (as you can see) is storing my object. My object is custom class and storing in the NSMutableArray.

I already added these methods inside of the my custom class

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is most likely in the `initWithCoder:` method of your custom class. It is leaking but the analyzer reports it as being in the archiver.

Unrelated to your problem, I would caution you against using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` to initialize collections, especially mutable collections. Instead use, `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]`. I've seen strange problems using just `init` that were cleared up by using `initWithCapacity`.

Comment: TechZen thank you again your quick response. So, what should i do for solving my problem ?

Comment: TechZen after see your answer i researched over the stackoverflow, Stefan von Chossy already gave an answer that related with my problem,  if someone have same problem like me, look at here :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults/751749#751749 

In the custom class you should use 
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
 self = [super init];

instead of;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
 
Thank you again

Comment: @fyasar Please post your solution as an answer, so that I can up-wote it. Switching from `self = [[MyObject alloc] init]` to `self = [super init]` does indeed solve the leak reported by profiling in Instruments.