# Do I need to use NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I have an object. It has only two NSStrings as properties.

I created an array to hold several of these objects.

Do I need to use NSKeyedArchiver to save this array to disk, or can I just use NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1):

If your object is a custom class, you will need to use `NSKeyedArchiver` before you put the contents in `NSUserDefaults`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537849/768472).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:myKey];` for writing and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:myKey];` for reading (there is no `setArray:forKey:` as it's not needed).

Also, if you got an array that you don't want to store inside NSUserDefaults there's an easy possibility to write and read arrays: [-[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:) and [+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile:). There also the same methods for NSDictionary to easily read/write dictionaries. Of course you're always free to use NSKeyed(Un)Archiver as well.

Comment: If I try to do that I get an "attempt to insert non-property value" error.

Comment: @awakeFromNib: What did you do ? I just verified with this code: `NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"TestKey"];` which works exactly as expected.