# How do I add an object into an NSMutableArray to be stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing custom objects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults)
>   [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

I tried to store an object instantiated from a class I wrote called "Animal" in an NSMutableArray to be stored in NSUserDefaults. However, I get this error.

```
[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<Animal: 0xcea7060>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

What does this mean? Perhaps I cannot store objects in NSMutableArrays to be stored in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2315948/); also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7459585/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/537044/, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/471830/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` can store arrays and dictionaries, mutable or not, but only if they contain property-list-legal classes (`NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSData`, and a few others). For other classes, you should [serialize the object(s) into an `NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)  before putting it into `NSUserDefaults` (or into a collection which you're putting into `NSUserDefaults` or writing to a property list).

Putting custom classes in `NSUserDefaults` doesn't happen often in most apps, so you might also consider whether your `Animal`s really belong there. Remember, `NSUserDefaults` is for settings, state, and other small things -- the data your app manages are better kept elsewhere. Use [archiving](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) or property lists to write files in your app's sandbox, or Core Data (or some other database) for such things.

Answer (score -3):

you may check out `Archive`or `Serialization`