# How to save an XML file?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. In it, I want to create an XML file with some data. I want to save the XML file and retrieve it at some other time. Is it possible to save and retrieve an XML file on the iPhone? If so, how?

Comment: -1: unclear, doesn't look like it was researched at all

Comment: Do you just want a yes or no answer :) answer is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with some NSDictionaries or NSArrays. It's basically the same stuff. NSUserDefaults writes some NSArrays or NSDictionary to the app folder on your device as an XML (Plist file).

The good thing is that it will be persistent during app lauches. Have a look [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/).

Comment: Please give me the example for nsuserdefaults with nsarray or nsdictionary

Comment: have a look here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults/537849#537849](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults/537849#537849)