# Save data on iPhone for single user

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering, if I had maybe 20 or so objects (numbers and strings) that i wanted saved for my app, would it be best to do this in a plist? or NSUserDefaults? or would I need to implement coredata?

Comment: NSUserDefaults won't be the best place. You can do it with CoreData, save it as a plist or save a file to disk, for example in JSON.

Comment: Well you can do it with NSUserDefaults if you like. But if you would like to store more complex objects Plists or CoreData would be better options. NSUserDefaults is typically used to store some user data or settings so NSUserDefaults wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: right, but the data wont be complex or anything, just maybe 20 ints or so

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSUserDefaults, if you only have to save 20 strings. it's the fastest way.

You can get an example here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults

You can also save an array in NSUserDefaults if you don't want to store 20 variables.

Anyway, if you have to store more complex objects, plists or coredata would be a better options.

Hope this helps

Comment: can I save an array of arrays?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is mostly used for user préférences if it's app data you need to store, core data is probably the way to go