# NSUserDefault to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Icstored the value of 2 label in NSUserDefault, trought NSMutableArray.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Add a bookmark
NSMutableDictionary *bookmark = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[bookmark setValue:author.text forKey:@"author"];
[bookmark setValue:book.text forKey:@"book"];
[bookmarks addObject:bookmark];

// Save your (updated) bookmarks
[userDefaults setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Now my problem is how retrieve the values of NSUserDefault trought NSArray?

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 self.dataArray = [prefs arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];

 NSString *author =  ?? 
 NSString *book =  ??
```

Comment: -1. Improper naming of objects. RTM.

Comment: You can't add NSArray to NSUserDefaults. See this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * author = [self.dataArray objectForKey: @"author"];
NSString * book = [self.dataArray objectForKey: @"book"];
```

This *assumes* you successfully saved the array and that you successfully re-loaded the array from `NSUserDefaults`.  You really should do some error checking in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the dataArray, you can store lots of bookmarks.This methods can log all of the bookmarks.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
self.dataArray = [prefs objectForKey:@"bookmarks"]; 

for(int i=0;i<[dataArray count];i++){
    NSDictionary *dic = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@"，dic);
    NSString * author = [dic objectForKey: @"author"];
    NSString * book = [dic objectForKey: @"book"];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have inserted an array with a dictionary. you can retrieve it by using

```
self.dataArray = [prefs arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"];
 NSString *author =  [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"author"]; 
 NSString *book =   [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"book"];
```

But it is better to store the dictionary directly in user defaults.

Comment: Thk for the reply. I use NSArray for make a cell of TableView for retrieve the data of NSUserDefault. is correct use NSArray?

Comment: Ya. It is ok to use NSArray if want it for that purpose.