# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex crashes on second execution

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a tableview with a number of rows that I want to be able to delete. The data that populates the tableview is stored in an NSMutableArray. To delete the data on one row I call:

```
- (void)deleteFromArray:(NSUInteger) number{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  //load NSUserDefaults
    NSMutableArray *storedArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    storedArray = [prefs objectForKey: @"mydata"];
    [storedArray removeObjectAtIndex:number];

    [prefs setObject:storedArray forKey:@"mydata"];
    [storedArray release];
    [prefs synchronize];

}
```

From

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        subscribe *subscribeclass = [subscribe alloc];
        [subscribeclass deleteFromArray: indexPath.row];
        [myTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This works fine the first time I delete a row. But when I delete a seconds row the application crashes on the following line in deleteFromArray:

```
[storedArray removeObjectAtIndex:number];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: Apparently your `storedArray` is an `NSArray`, that's why you can't call that method.

Comment: what are you storing inside the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array coming from your NSUserDefaults is a NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. You should modify your code to be like this:

```
- (void)deleteFromArray:(NSUInteger) number{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  //load NSUserDefaults
    NSMutableArray *storedArray = [[prefs objectForKey:@"mydata"] mutableCopy];
    [storedArray removeObjectAtIndex:number];

    [prefs setObject:storedArray forKey:@"mydata"];
    [storedArray release];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

This creates a copy of the immutable array and makes it mutable, so that you can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The things you can only store immutable NSArrays in defaults. Even if the object is mutable, it is stored as immutable

So instead of

```
 NSMutableArray *storedArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 storedArray = [prefs objectForKey: @"mydata"];
```

try:

```
 [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[prefs objectForKey: @"mydata"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the array returned from objectForKey is immutable.
So you can see what other people do:[Storing custom objects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults)