# Saving NSArray to NSUserDefaults is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save an `NSArray` of objects to `NSUserDefaults`, but when I pull the `NSArray` back out with `getObject` it contains nothing.

I put a break point here to count objects and verify there are items in the array

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mappingResult.array forKey:kArrayOfFoundThings];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Here is where I pull them out and the array says nothing is inside.

```
NSArray *allAmbulances = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kArrayOfFoundThings];
```

Comment: Do the objects in the array conform to NSCoding?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that objects contained in your array are conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol, you could use

```
// let's take the NSString as example
NSArray *array = @[@"foo", @"bar"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array] forKey:@"annotationKey"];
NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"annotationKey"]] ;
```

If they are conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, then

```
// let's take the NSString as example
NSArray *array = @[@"foo", @"bar"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: array forKey:@"annotationKey"];
NSArray *archivedArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"annotationKey"] ;
```

**EDIT**

Ok, probably it's not working for `NSArray` of objects conforming to `NSCopying` protocol, but it arguably works for the objects conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol as pointed out by Brad Larson in the following answer:

[Storing custom objects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: I would not misuse NSUserDefaults that much, it's primarily settings storage. But the solution is working, so +1.

Comment: @Andy Good point, I totally agree with you...Anyway I tried to give an answer to the jgervin question. I might have caught the wrong question =)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation:

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and
>   NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

Are the contents of the array NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects?