# iOS and NSCoding: is this the correct way to encode an NSMutableArray with custom objects?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, encode, nscoding

I have this class with an `NSMutableArray` of custom Cocos2d objects implementing the `NSCoding` protocol.

```
@interface PlayerData : NSObject <NSCoding> {
}

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *levelsStars; //Where levelsStars is filled with objects conforming to the NSCoding protocol.
```

The objects are of type `LevelData`, which inherits from `CCNode` (a Cocos2d class) and conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.

```
@interface LevelData : CCNode <NSCoding>
```

Here is the implementation of the protocol in `PlayerData`. In order to encode and decode the `NSMutableArray` of custom Cocos2d objects, which conform to `NSCoding` objects:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:levelsStars] forKey:kLevelsStars];
}


-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Reading arrays:
        NSData * dataRepresentingLevelStars = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kLevelsStars];
        if (dataRepresentingLevelStars!=nil) {
            NSArray * oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingLevelStars];
            if (dataRepresentingLevelStars!=nil) {
                levelsStars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldSavedArray];
            }
            else
            {
                levelsStars = [[NSMutableArray array] initWithCapacity:10];
            }
        }

    }

    return self;
}
```

Is this approach correct? I based it on this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults).

**EDIT:** I thought I will add some more details on my use case

My users can choose among different characters, each characters corresponds to a PlayerData object which I plan to store in a different file appending the user's game center id (id-character1.archive, id-character2.archive etc..).

I do save progress of the characters in the object (e.g. score, life) including the NSMutableArray custom array of Cocos2d-objects (in my real case I do have 5 different arrays containing 20/30 objects each).

Comment: Please refer to answer of this question. I hope this will answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to use NSUserDefaults and hence I am asking if my understanding and implementation of the solution I linked is correct..

Comment: yes it is correct but i would recommend you to use it only for small data otherwise it is very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, why is it very small? My use case is: my users can choose among different characters, each characters corresponds to a PlayerData object and I do save progress of the characters in the object (e.g. score, life) including the NSMutableArray custom array of Cocos2d-objects (in my real case I do have 5 different arrays containing 20/30 objects each).

Comment: 30 objects in 5 different arrays = 150 objects. coding and decoding in NSData is slow. I would reccomend you to store it in seperate plist file instead of coding or decoding, That will increase your coding efforts but will improve performance of app.

Comment: I will test it and then use the plist if doesn't perform properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your main init method for the PlayerData object you want to do the unarchive:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.levelsStars = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathToArchive];
        if (self.levelsStars == nil) self.levelsStars = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```

This will then call initWithCoder: on each of your objects that was in the array. And pull them back into a mutable array.

You will want to have some method for saving your data though, again on your PlayerData object:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.levelsStars toFile:pathToArchive];
}
```

This will call encodeWithCoder: on each of the objects in the array and write them out to a file.

Comment: From my understanding the archive and unarchive object with data works only with NSData objects and, given I have a NSMutable array with custom objects I have to encode this in a NSData object first (as in my solution). Is there something wrong in my solution?

Comment: Is your playerData object your highest level object, or is it archived out by another class?

Comment: In the comments someone has said that your way works fine, so maybe stick with it, it just seems overly complicated to me...

Comment: there is static manager class that loads and unloads PlayerData according to the character being currently selected. Is there somewhere a good design pattern reference/tutorial for this type of problems as far as u know?

Comment: So the static manager should be the only one calling to NSKeyedArchiver or NSKeyedUnarchiver to archive either the player or an array of players. Then the custom player class should just implement NSCoding along with the custom playerStars class.