# How to save custom objects in array and store it in NSUserDefaults - iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsuserdefaults

I am getting my custom class object after button action method. Now I need to store multiple custom objects in `NSMutableArray` and then store this array in `NSUserDefaults`.

Here is my code :

```
-(IBAction)onClickSubmitLater:(id)sender
{
    //Saving store in user defaults for later upload data.

    NSMutableArray *arrayStoreList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayStoreList = [Util getArrayPreference:@"Store"];//arrayStoreList is the list of all stores.

    Store *store = [[Store alloc] init];
    store = [arrayStoreList objectAtIndex:self.selectedStoreIndex];//here i am getting particular store that i need to save in array.

    //archive
    NSData *dataStore = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:store];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataStore forKey:@"resultStore"];

    //unarchive
    NSData *dataResultStore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"resultStore"];

    Store *resultStore = (Store *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataResultStore];
    NSLog(@"%@", resultStore);
}
```

Using above code, it is saving single Custom class `Store` object in `NSUserDefaults`. So I would like to save all `Store` object in `NSMutableArray` after submit later ibaction. Later, I will fetch array of stores for uploading store on server one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: - (void) encodeWithCoder : (NSCoder *)encode ;
- (id) initWithCoder : (NSCoder *)decode; i have implemented in Store entity. Why downvote ?

Comment: NSUserDefaults are used for storing preferences, so ask this question to yourself "Is it necessary to use NSUserDefaults"? There are many other option to persist data like storing as plist, using coder and decoder etc. There is a beautiful reusable class written by nick lockwood, Have a look at https://github.com/nicklockwood/BaseModel . I suggest you using it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, according to my requirement, i have to use userDefaults. After stop an app from Xcode. it will remains the same store.

Answer (score 19):

To store and retrieve array with custom object on user defaults you can use following methods:

```
-(void)writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults:(NSString *)keyName withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:keyName];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:keyName];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [defaults synchronize];
    return myArray; 
}
```

But make sure you have implemented

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder : (NSCoder *)encode ;
- (id) initWithCoder : (NSCoder *)decode;
```

method in data model class to avoid crash as followings:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:label forKey:@"label"];
    [coder encodeInteger:numberID forKey:@"numberID"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        label = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"label"] retain];
        numberID = [[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"numberID"] retain];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me and also thanks for avoid crash.

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair Do i have to use `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` anywhere in the code?

Comment: you must have to implement, otherwise will not work!

Comment: But you are not using anywhere! Actually i didn't get this

Comment: You have to implement that for your model

Comment: as example you have 2 properties names label & numberID, you have to implement those method like 
`- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:label forKey:@"label"];
    [coder encodeInteger:numberID forKey:@"numberID"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        label = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"label"] retain];
        numberID = [[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"numberID"] retain];
    }   
    return self;
}`

otherwise you will get crash.

Answer (score 2):

You need to archive it by implementing `NSCoding` protocol. Then you can write it to any file.

Implement these methods in your model :

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder : (NSCoder *)encode ;
- (id) initWithCoder : (NSCoder *)decode;
```

As you say, you have implemented this in the Class, now you need to save the array.

For saving and reading the array, you need to use :;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMutableArray forKey:@"keyForArray"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"keyForArray"]];
```

Comment: then what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks Anoop..here using my above code i am storing only one store object "resultStore" in Userdefaults. But i need to create an array here and then store all store objects in it.

Comment: So your problem is dealing with array? check my edited answer

Comment: It is showing [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<Store: 0x88a2530>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM' in console.

Answer (score 1):

This two methods will mainly used to `store` and `retrieve` custom object's property.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder ;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
```

Take look at @chrissr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/2301271), @Brad Larson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults/537849#537849)

Comment: Thanks mani, i have implemented above NSCoding methods in store entity class.

Comment: If those comments helped you, give tick or upvotes for visitor's attention. :)

Comment: Correct @mani, but my problem is to save all Store object in NSMutableArray. using above code i am saving one class object in Userdefaults. like this first i need to add all store in an array and then store this array in userdefault.

Comment: Did you see @Brad Larson's answer which I've added link?

Comment: Dude You said that you have used his code to implement above method than you have to show respect and give him up vote.+1