# How to set Default Object at indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I want to save data to a specific index in my table.

Here's what I want to achieve theoretically:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:cell.label.text forKey:indexPath];
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:cell.label.text forKey:[indexPath description]];
```

Comment: `[indexPath description]` seems to be that thing I need. I will give you feedback as soon as I get everything working :D BTW How do I turn `[indexPath description]` back to an indexPath for loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the all the data that is relevant to the tableview in an array and store this array in standard user defaults.

**EDIT**

You CAN use NSUserDefaults for storing other objects than it originially supports. 
Follow this question here: 
[How to save custom objects in array and store it in NSUserDefaults - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627713/how-to-save-custom-objects-in-array-and-store-it-in-nsuserdefaults-iphone)

Comment: Not if that data contains objects other than `NSDate`, `NSData`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSArray`.

Comment: How do I store it in an array so that when I load the defaults, all of my cell labels get the correct texts at the correct indexPaths? I would have to also store the NSIndexPath in the array I assume.

Comment: 4 Sections with 4 Rows in each.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify code as below

```
NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userdefaults setObject:cell.label.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$$%d",indexPath.row]]; // modify as per your requirement
[userdefaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieving you can as below.

```
NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

cell.textLabel.text=[userdefaults valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$$%d",indexPath.row]]; //modify as per your requirement
```

Hope it helps you...!