# Saving array using NSUserDefaults crashes app

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, saving-data

I feel as if I am doing things correctly, but I am getting an error at the end of my data conversion and retrieval. Please see the code below:

```
class Task:NSObject, NSCoding {
        var name:String
        var notes:String
        var date:NSDate
        var taskCompleted:Bool

        init(name:String, notes:String,date:NSDate, taskCompleted:Bool){
            self.name = name
            self.notes = notes
            self.date = date
            self.taskCompleted = taskCompleted
        }

        required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
            self.name = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String?)!
            self.notes = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("notes") as! String?)!
            self.date = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as! NSDate?)!
            self.taskCompleted = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("taskCompleted") as! Bool?)!
        }

        func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
            coder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
            coder.encodeObject(self.notes, forKey: "notes")
            coder.encodeObject(self.date, forKey: "date")
            coder.encodeObject(self.taskCompleted, forKey: "taskCompleted")
        }
    }
```

I then save and get the data as follows:

```
let nowData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject([nowTasks])
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(nowData, forKey: "nowData")

let loadedData = defaults.dataForKey("nowData")
let loadedArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData!) as! [Task]
```

When I call `print(loadedArray.first)` I get the error: **NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type**

Comment: Post the message that gets printed to the console when it crashes

Comment: And you have to implement the `NSCoding` protocol to archive a class with `NSKeyedArchiver`

Comment: Added error codes above

Comment: You need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol and make your `Task` a subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627713/how-to-save-custom-objects-in-array-and-store-it-in-nsuserdefaults-iphone

Comment: Please see updated question @dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code should work fine even with some really weird forced casting going on in your decoder method. Try like this:

```
class Task: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name = String()
    var notes = String()
    var date: NSDate
    var taskCompleted: Bool
    init(name: String, notes: String, date: NSDate, taskCompleted: Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
        self.date = date
        self.taskCompleted = taskCompleted
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.notes = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("notes") as! String
        self.date = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as! NSDate
        self.taskCompleted = decoder.decodeBoolForKey("taskCompleted")
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encodeObject(notes, forKey: "notes")
        coder.encodeObject(date, forKey: "date")
        coder.encodeBool(taskCompleted, forKey: "taskCompleted")
    }
}
```

Testing with plist files:

```
let task1 = Task(name: "task1", notes: "note a", date: NSDate(), taskCompleted: false)
let task2 = Task(name: "task2", notes: "note b", date: NSDate(), taskCompleted: true)

let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")

if let filePath = fileURL.path {
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject([task1,task2], toFile: filePath)
    if let loadedArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as? [Task] {
        print(loadedArray.count)

        print(loadedArray.first?.name ?? "")
        print(loadedArray.first?.notes ?? "")
        print(loadedArray.first!.date )
        print(loadedArray.first!.taskCompleted)

        print(loadedArray.last?.name ?? "")
        print(loadedArray.last?.notes ?? "")
        print(loadedArray.last!.date )
        print(loadedArray.last!.taskCompleted)
    }
}
```

Comment: After some time working with the above code I managed to get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question though. Can I use the same .plist file to save multiple arrays? Do I retrieve them using the same `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myArray, toFile: filePath)` for the same filePath?

Comment: you can but I think it would be easier for you to use a plist file for each array. You can save your plist files inside the preferences folder at the library directory