# Saving data with NSUserDetaults and load after phone restart wont work

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

I managed to save an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults by first converting it to NSData - I dont deal with a lot of data and just want the data to be there after I switch off & on my phone - but the data does not show up in my table where I would display it. I write the NSUserDefaults back to my array upon loading. Maybe one of you has a hint...? Below the button action where I write to NSUserDefaults and the method viewDidLoad where I write NSUserDefaults to my original array (toDoitems)

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    XYZAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
     if (item !=nil) {
        [self.toDoitems addObject:item];
        NSString *error;
        NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:self.toDoitems format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"itemArray"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.toDoitems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"itemArray"]];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this: `[self.tableView reloadData];` be in viewDidAppear in your `XYZAddToDoItemViewController`? And after you set: `self.toDoitems` of course

Comment: This should answer it as well as close it...possible duplicate of [Storing custom objects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537044/storing-custom-objects-in-an-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: I tried the [self.tableView reloadData]; in viewDidLoad but didnt help. How could I check that there is actually data in NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres one way to do this

1. Add encoder decoder functions to your XYZToDoItem class
   Something like this if say you had 2 strings in this class string1 and string2 :
   (i havent compiled this code but you get the idea)

   ```
   -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder

   {
   [aCoder encodeObject:self.string1 forKey:@"string1"];
   [aCoder encodeObject:self.string2 forKey:@"string2"];
    }

   -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
   {

   self = [super init];

   if (self) 
   {
       self.string1 = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"string1"];
       self.string2 = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"string2"];
   }

   return self;
   }
   ```
2. Then when you are ready to save do the following

   ```
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.myDataArray];
   [userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"storageName"];

   // To load the data from NSUserDefaults
   NSData *myData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"storageName"];
   NSArray *temp = (NSMutableArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
   self.myDataArray =  (NSMutableArray*)[temp mutableCopy];
   ```