# How to save tableView data to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Hey guys i have a tableView and when the view is closed or left from, the tableViews data is saved! Could someone please provide some source code?? ANy help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks :D
-Kurt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the data from the tableview cell and save that to saveString..

```
    NSString *saveString;   

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    [prefs setObject:saveString forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];//saving an nsstring 
    NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];//retrieving the string
```

[Source](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)
**EDIT :1**
To save the data from the array to the NSString:

```
NSString *saveString=[yourArray objectAtindex:0];
```

then save the saveString in the NSUerdefaults.
**EDIT :2**
There are two options for you to store the array in the NSUserDefaults.
First one:
If you are having 10 elements in the array means Create 10 NSString and store in that strings.
Second one:
[store the array in the nsuserdefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350848/possible-to-save-an-integer-array-using-nsuserdefaults-on-iphone)

Comment: hmm doesnt this only save the nsstring?? Is there a way i can save a tableView's text?? like its cell's text?

Comment: How you are adding the text in the tableview?

Comment: i have a plist called "cells.plist" and im storing that data into an NSMutableArray called "cellText"

Comment: do you want to save the text from the array to nsuserdefaults ?

Comment: yep exactly. in the app i can add cells to the tableView and i want to be able to save those too so when the user opens the app back up everything will be there!

Comment: okay, now do i have to do this for each index in the array? or is there a way to save each object in the array to this 1 string? And thanks a lot for the help :D