# 'Program received signal: SIGABRT' when inserting object to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

When I try to insert an object to my NSMutableArray I am getting a 'Program received signal: SIGABRT' error, however I don't understand why.

Here is my code, specifically it's the `insertObject:value` that is causing the error.

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[myDictionary setValue:valueName.text forKey:kValueName];
[myDictionary setObject:subValuesList forKey:kSubValuesList];

MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int position = appDelegate.position;

NSMutableArray *valuesList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kValuesArray];
[valuesList insertObject:myDictionary atIndex:position];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values returned from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value.

You need to make a mutable copy after you retrieve the array from `NSUserDefaults`. Luckily for you, `NSArray` conforms to the `NSMutableCopying` protocol, so you just have to send a `mutableCopy` message to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *valuesList = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kValuesArray] mutableCopy];
```

Keep in mind that you own the object returned by `mutableCopy` as per the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). In other words, you need to release it when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save and retrieve the array using NSData. Possible dup.

[Possible to save an integer array using NSUserDefaults on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350848/possible-to-save-an-integer-array-using-nsuserdefaults-on-iphone)